# Delay in script is not working

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, canvas, timer

I have a sleep function object in javascript-

```
    function sleep(ms) { 
        var d = new Date(); 
        var target=d.getTime()+ms; 
        var next = d; 
        console.log('Slept');
        while(next.getTime()<=target) {
            next=new Date(); 
        }
        console.log('Woke Up');
        return;
    }
```

Using this `sleep(5000)` prints out (in console)

```
Slept
```

and after 5 seconds

```
Woke Up
```

This code also works fine - `alert('foo'); sleep(5000); alert('bar');`
First `foo` and 5 seconds later `bar`.

But this function

```
//ctx is a 2d context of a canvas
function go() {
    ctx.fillRect(100,100,200,200); 
    sleep(1000); 
    ctx.fillRect(200,200,300,300); 
    sleep(1000);
    ctx.fillRect(300,300,400,400); 
    sleep(1000);
    ctx.fillRect(400,400,500,500);
}

go();
```

is not working. I mean it is working but not the way it should. First the console shows -

```
Slept
//1 second later
Woke Up  
//1 second later  
Slept
//1 second later
Woke Up
Slept
//1 second later
Woke Up
```

and after all these messages are printed, the figures (rectangles) are drawn on the canvas.
Is there a way to get this done without using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`?

**Question** - Why is the `fillRect` not working with my `sleep` function?
And Is there a way to delay some code in javascript without using `setTimeout` and `setInterval`?

Comment: "*Is there a way to get this done without using setTimeout or setInterval?*" Is there a particular reason you can't or don't you want to use those? Timers are typically the preferred way to delay code execution as they allow other code/events to continue functioning in the meantime.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I am avoiding those because a bunch of actions need to be performed. Putting them in a callback and then using `clearTimeout` after a certain condition is met becomes really messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implement your sleep() function as asynchronous (i.e. setTimeout() or setInterval()). The way you did it, it is blocking all actions of the browser, such as rendering and painting; your rectangles are drawn only after you return the control to the browser.

Comment: Because alert() works in a blocking way, too - it interrupts your js thread immediately.

Answer (score 1):

"*Is there a way to get this done without using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`?*" No, not really. You need the separation between each step to be asynchronous and timers are that.

The issue is, as long as `sleep(...)` is running, it's ***blocking*** the UI thread. Until that's *free* again, the browser can't update the display with the shapes you're drawing.

Giving the execution even a 1 ms break gives it enough time to update between steps:

```
function go() {
    ctx.fillRect(100,100,200,200);
    sleep(1000);
    ctx.fillRect(200,200,300,300);
    sleep(1000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        ctx.fillRect(300,300,400,400);
        sleep(1000);
        ctx.fillRect(400,400,500,500);
    }, 1);
}
```

Comment: Why can't it work with canvas methods when it is working fine with `alert`?

Comment: @SandyLee How dialogs, like `alert`, work are actually up to the developers of the browser -- they're not truly standardized. But, typically what you see is they work because they get their own thread and pause the UI thread until they're dismissed. The `<canvas>`, on the other hand, depends entirely on the same thread that's executing your JavaScript and managing the UI.